# There comes a more `/` in the front of `??` when I request the url

Tags: python, django

I have a url in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^delete_server_snapshot??(?P<snapshot_server_id>\[0-9a-z\-]+)/', app_admin_views.delete_server_snapshot),  # here 
    ...
```

And when I request it, there is in template:

```
<td><a href="/app_admin/delete_server_snapshot??{{ snapshot_server.id }}/" type="button" class="btn-de">Delete</a></td>
```

But when I click the `<a>` tag, there comes error, there comes a more `/` in the front of `??`:

[image]

The request url:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8001/app_admin/delete_server_snapshot/??70e6e179-6269-445c-bd6a-cd98e55b1bdb/
```

Comment: Why are you using `\[` in your regular expression? By escaping the `[` you *disabled the character class*. It does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How to use it? I  tried [0-9a-z\-]+ still not works for me.

Comment: I suspect that the `??` is somehow confusing the urlpattern reverser. Why do you have `??` in the URL in the first place? That seems to be a surprising addition.

Comment: Yes, you should remove the `\` in front of the `[`. Your problem is a different one, escaping the character class is not a solution to that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because I use the `?` has this issue, so I changed to `??`, but still have the issue.

Comment: Please don't start making random changes to your URL patterns. Start with the simplest pattern that produces the error. My question then becomes, *why do you have a question mark in your URL?*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put question marks in your URL pattern, full stop. The `?<query string>` part of the URL is *never* used in a URL pattern; any query parameters are accessible via the request object instead and can't be used to match URLs.

From the [*What the URLconf searches against* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against):

> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name.

The GET parameters come from the query string, everything after the `?` comma.

If you want the `snapshot_server_id` identifier to be part of the URL to match on, remove the question marks altogether:

```
url(r'^delete_server_snapshot(?P<snapshot_server_id>[0-9a-z\-]+)/', app_admin_views.delete_server_snapshot)
```

You can use `/` as a delimiter if you need one between `snapshot` and the UUID, or any other [valid URL path character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax).

The `?` character tells Django that your URL path ends at that location, and a `/` is inserted at the end of the path of the generated URL.

Comment: thank you, I use the `_` replace the `??` works for me too, your answer let me know the `?` character function in Django urlpatterns.